# Azure PostgreSQL instances data abnormally incresing

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-postgresql

I am having an instance of Azure PostgreSQL. I am using this instance for development purpose. And only I use this instance for now. But, this instance is increasing its size automatically even without access or no activity.

[image]

This month I did not open or use this instance for a single time but already it's showing 2.84gb used. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Database for PostgreSQL - Flexible Server is a fully managed database service. The architecture separates compute and storage. The storage maintains three locally redundant synchronous copies of the database files ensuring data durability.
The service performs automated patching of the underlying hardware, OS, and database engine.
The flexible server service automatically creates server backups and stores them on zone redundant storage (ZRS) within the region.

**Irrespective of the database size, heavy transactional activity on the server generates more WAL files. The increase in files in turn increases the backup storage.**

Please check for redundancy options selected and backup retention period too.

We recommend to actively monitor the disk space that is in use, and increase the disk size ahead of any out of storage situation. You can set up an alert to notify you when your server storage is approaching out of disk so you can avoid any issues with running out of disk. For more information, see the documentation on [how to set up an alert.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/howto-alert-on-metrics)

Comment: All my data could be max 100mb.